# Ubuntu 22.04 Screen Brightness Remains Dim If Not Logging On Immediately

Tags: boot, 22.04, screen, brightness, backlight

Ever since I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 I've been having a problem with the screen brightness if I don't log on immediately after booting.

Steps to reproduce:

- Boot Ubuntu 22.04
- After boot, don't log in right away. Allow the screen saver to kick in.
- Hit Enter (or any other key) and the list of users is displayed, but the screen is dimmer than normal.
- Log in. Notice that the screen brightness is reduced from the normal or last brightness level.

Note 1: This screen dimming problem doesn't occur if I lock the screen and log back in.

Per some other threads, I have tried adding acpi_backlight=vendor to the /etc/default/grub line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"

But that change has no effect.

The only workaround so far is to use the "Fn" key and the appropriate function key to reset the screen brightness.

Note 2: This behavior did not occur on Ubuntu 18.04

Machine specs: Sony Vaio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a setting that worked by reading the specifications in this article:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Backlight

The article lists the various acceptable values for the acpi_backlight setting.

What worked for me was editing /etc/default/grub using

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and changing the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX parameter from this:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash **acpi_backlight=vendor**
to this:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash **acpi_backlight=native**

then running `sudo update-grub`,
then restarting Ubuntu.

Further information:

After changing the value for acpi_backlight, and after update-grub and restarting,
running

```
ls -l /sys/class/backlight/
```

will show the drivers currently in use.

In my case, acpi_backlight=vendor showed

sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight

sys/class/backlight/sony

while acpi_backlight=native showed only

sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight

So it's likely that Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't like something about the Sony driver